# React Slick in mobile view

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, slick.js, mobile-website, web-frontend

I am using the react slick library in the react app it is working properly in desktop view but in mobile view (480px) not working even though I used the proper object of the library with the breakpoint 480 still it is hurting me.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

code...
var settings = {
dots: true,
infinite: false,
speed: 500,
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
initialSlide: 0,
autoplay: false,
arrows:true,
adaptiveHeight:true,

```
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2,
        initialSlide: 1
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true,
        autoplay: false,

      }
    }
  ]
};
```

I used React slick library in React app
I want to display images in the slider in an efficient way

Comment: can you please provide your react code as well?